# How to display data in a reusable Table component in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, ant-design-blazor

I'm trying to create a reusable MasterTable component in Blazor.

So far, I've defined the MasterTable as

```
@using AntDesign
@using MyNamespace.Blazor.ViewModels

@typeparam TItem

<Table TItem="TItem" DataSource="@Data">
    @{
        foreach (var col in Columns)
        {
            <Column Title="@col.Label" @bind-Field="@col.Key" />
        }
    }
</Table>

@code
{

    private List<TItem> _data;
    [Parameter]
    public List<TItem> Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set => _data = value ?? new List<TItem>();
    }

    [Parameter]
    public TableColumnViewModel[] Columns { get; set; }
}
```

where TableColumnViewModel is defined simply as

```
public class TableColumnViewModel
{         
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create an instance of the MasterTable in a page for Daily Tasks but so far I'm only able to get it to display like this:

[image]

My attempt to implement MasterTable is as follows:

```
@page "/Tasks/Daily";
@using MyNamespace.Blazor.Services;
@using MyNamespace.Blazor.ViewModels;
@using MyNamespace.Api.Client.Model;

@inject ITasksService _tasksService;

<h1>Daily Tasks</h1>

<MasterTable TItem="TaskStatus" Data="_tasks" Columns="cols">
</MasterTable>

@code {
    private List<TaskStatus> _tasks = new List<TaskStatus>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _tasks = await _tasksService.GetTaskStatusAsync();
    }
    
    TableColumnViewModel[] cols = 
    {
        new TableColumnViewModel
        {
            Key = "id",
            Label = "ID"
        },
        new TableColumnViewModel
        {
            Key = "description",
            Label = "ID"
        },
        new c
        {
            Key = "type",
            Label = "Type"
        }
    };
}
```

With TaskStatus defined as

```
public class TaskStatus
{
   
    public TaskStatus(int taskStatusId = default(int), string statusDescription = default(string))
    {
        this.TaskStatusId = taskStatusId;
        this.StatusDescription = statusDescription;
    }
   
    public int TaskStatusId { get; set; }  
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
}
```

What do I need to do to get the MasterTable template to display the list of TaskStatus objects instead of the keys from TableColumnViewModel?

To be clear - instead of just using the  component without wrapping it, the issue is that I want to isolate the CSS in the context of the 3rd party component, so that *only* the necessary CSS is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You never seem to use the DataSource of the Table component. For a working example you might have a look at [Creating a DataGrid component in Blazor](https://www.meziantou.net/creating-a-datagrid-component-in-blazor.htm).